# How to customize the docker gcc command and add own path instead of /usr/src

Tags: gcc, docker

I'm trying to compile a C file named test.c using docker's gcc container.

I'm using the following command, I have put the test.c in my `home`in ubuntu.

```
sudo docker run -v /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/:/myapp.c:ro gcc:4.9 sh -c "gcc -o myapp /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/myapp.c; ./myapp"
```

It works cool, but, I want to change the folder from `home` to a folder inside my eclipse web project folder. I have an editor on a web page and then on compile it creates a test.c file inside a folder. I want to access that file.

I tried adding the path like `/home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file` but I get the error

```
   gcc: error: /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/myapp.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
sh: 1: ./myapp: not found
```

Comment: Did you try using an absolute path like the error suggests? e.g. /home/me/workspace/Web Content/...

Comment: @AdrianMouat yes, sir.

Comment: @AdrianMouat the it gives  `No such file or directory` error

Comment: To be honest, it just sounds like you made a typo. Can you add to the question the exact  command you execute and the result of running ls on the path?

Comment: I bet the space between Web and Content was not quoted.

Comment: @AdrianMouat `/home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file` There is no space in WebContent

Comment: @YehCheez There's a space in the error message.

Comment: That was just an example @AdrianMouat

Comment: @YehCheez Your error message was just an example?! No-one can help you if you don't post the commands you are using and the resultant error message. Bonus points if you can make it portable so we can try it out and see what happens.

Comment: @AdrianMouat okay that was stupid of me. I'll edit the question, out up proper errors and then ping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about several things here.

The `-v HOST_PATH:CON_PATH` argument can be used to mount files inside a container, as you seem to be attempting. The `HOST_PATH` can be a file or a directory. The `CON_PATH` determines where that file or directory will be in the container. In your case, I think you want:

```
-v /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/myapp.c:/myapp.c
```

Not just `...file/:/myapp.c`. I'm not sure what you expected your version to do (how can a directory be mapped to a file?).

Also, in the shell command you give the path on the host, but as this is processed in the container, you need the path in the container i.e:

```
gcc -o myapp /myapp.c
```

Putting it together, I would expect to see something like:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/myapp.c:/myapp.c:ro gcc:4.9 sh -c "gcc -o myapp /myapp.c; ./myapp"
```

Comment: Wow! that was it. What you said is absolutely correct. I had also tried this command: `sudo docker run -v /home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/:/myapp.c:ro gcc:4.9 sh -c "gcc -o myapp /myapp.c; ./myapp"` So i guess I was kind of there. But thank you

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help. It would help if you were a bit more precise in future though :)

Comment: I do have another question too though :P when using the Java container, I use the following command `sudo docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp java:7 javac Main.java` and if the `Main.java` doesn't have any errors it compiles and creates a `Main.class` file. If it has any errors it shows the errors in json format. Now, if the program has a `System.out.print` line, how do I show that as an output. I mean, if there are no errors it just compiles the program, i need the output of the program.

Comment: Okay. Update: I found out how to do it. just by running java filename. but how do I run the .class file created of the file that i run through my workspace? Because I can't find it at `/home/moomal/workspace/FypProject/WebContent/file/` nor is it at `home` directory

Comment: You need to take some time to understand how volumes work. https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/ http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/

If it still doesn't make sense after reading those, open a new question.

Comment: So i had to put up a new question. Can you please help? [stackoverflow.com/questions/28811290/compile-a-java-file-using-docker-with-own-path]