# Compile a java file using docker with own path

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker, javac

Hy. I'm trying to compile a .java file using docker. I read the files on docker's website, also I read these links:

[docker's website](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

[about volumes](http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/)

[and another question I had put up for gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622330/how-to-customize-the-docker-gcc-command-and-add-own-path-instead-of-usr-src/28660059?noredirect=1#comment45646021_28660059)

I understood the concept for the gcc compiler since it doesn't create any extra file for compiling. 
But the java one does. It creates a `Main.class` file on my /home directory if I use the following command and compile a file named `Main.java`

`sudo docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp java:7 javac Main.java`

after learning from the above links I was able to successfully compile a java file with my own path using:

```
docker run --rm -v /mypathhere/mycode.java:/mycode.java: java:7 javac mycode.java"
```

if there is any error it shows an error but if there isn't it just compiles and gives me no output, and that's justified because it creates a `Main.class` file.

My problem is that I am unable to find that `Main.class` file. I don't know where docker is creating it and I have zero understanding for it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.class` file will be inside the container, under the root directory.

The best plan is to mount the whole source directory and have `javac` put the result to the same directory e.g:

```
docker run --rm -v /mypathhere:/mycode java:7 sh -c "cd mycode; javac mycode.java"
```

That way, you should get the class file written to the `mypathhere` directory.

Apologies if that doesn't quite work - it's off the top of my head. Hopefully you get the idea though.

Comment: It gives the following error. 
`mycode.java:1: error: error while writing mycode: mycode.class (Read-only file system)
class mycode {
^
1 error`

Comment: Ooops - I had a spurious ":" after mycode. Try it again; I just tested and it works for me.

Comment: lol. Thats great! When my project is complete, I'll add a special thanks to you :')

Comment: hi looks like i need your help once again. Sorry but can you please guide me out?