# How to build and run a java instance in Docker

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to learn my way around Docker. [I want to build a container/image for my java application.](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) The Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:7

COPY . C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project1/src/mainpckg

WORKDIR C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project1/src/mainpckg

RUN javac Main.java

CMD java Main
```

And i am calling it like this:

```
docker build -t my-java-app .
```

But it gives the following error:

```
$ docker build -t my-java-app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM openjdk:7
 ---> 4a42f05dc422
Step 2 : COPY . C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project1
/src/mainpckg
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 301de702fad9
Step 3 : WORKDIR C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project1
s/src/mainpckg
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1868e40b329e
Step 4 : RUN javac Main.java
 ---> Running in 66d7d769f425
javac: file not found: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
The command '/bin/sh -c javac Main.java' returned a non-zero code:
 2
```

I also tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811290/compile-a-java-file-using-docker-with-own-path):

```
docker run --rm -v /mypathhere/mycode java:7 sh -c "cd mycode; javac mycode.java"
```

but without any results, i still got this error:

```
javac: file not found: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: Openjdk container is based on debian Linux distribution, I don't think `C:/...` is a valid path. Do you want to try it with something like `/app` and see if that works better?

Answer (score 1):

There is something fishy about C:/. Try following, it must work

```
FROM java:8

# add the container directory from the host
RUN mkdir /opt/mainpckg

# copy the app to container directory
ADD . /opt/mainpckg

WORKDIR /opt/mainpckg

RUN javac Main.java

CMD java Main
```

Comment: I am confused as to what your directories are suppose to point at. If set them exactly as you have how does Docker know where to look for the Main.java?

Comment: @Angelo Uknown As you see in the Dockefile, you have copied all your app files from host system to docker directory /opt/mainpckg at step 3 and set this directory as your present working directory at 4th step. So you are set to issue java commands being at present working directory /opt/mainpckg where your Main.Java resides. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you run with `-v /mypathhere/mycode`, as it [creates a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/adding-a-data-volume) which would overlay (temporarily overwrite) anything that was `/mypathhere/mycode` from the Dockerfile.

So try running *without* the `-v` part, in case `/mypathhere/mycode` is `C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project1` (assuming you are using Docker on Windows with Windows containers)

Comment: Now i got the following `is not a valid repository/tag.`